# Very Strange Error When Building an Android ROM image (based on AOSP)

Tags: android, c++, assembly, arm, dalvik

When I build the Android 4.3 ROM image for a Nexus 10 device (ARM7a) using the [Android Open Source Project (AOSP)](https://source.android.com/source/building.html) guidelines, the image works fine with no problem. However, when I add the following inline assembly code (adapted from [here](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/master/src/cycleclock.h#L111)) to the Android [Stack.cpp](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp) source file:

```
{uint32_t pmccntr;asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr));t0=static_cast<int64_t>(pmccntr) * 64;} 
//The C++ statement to measure its execution time 
{uint32_t pmccntr;asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr));t1=static_cast<int64_t>(pmccntr) * 64;} 
time = t1-t0;
```

I get the follwong compiler error message:

```
Error: no such instruction: `mrc p15,0,%eax,c9,c13,0'
```

**Notice that** I never used **eax** in my added inline assembly code, however, the compiler error message shows **eax**.

According to the command line `adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo`,
my device CPU is `ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)`

My build environment (according to the Android build **mm** command inside the directory [/dalvik/vm/interp/](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/dalvik/vm/interp/) which contains the Stack.cpp file) is

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL 
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.3 
TARGET_PRODUCT=full_manta 
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng 
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release 
TARGET_BUILD_APPS= 
TARGET_ARCH=arm 
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon 
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a15 
HOST_ARCH=x86 
HOST_OS=linux 
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.16.0-70-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.‌​04-trusty
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release 
BUILD_ID=JWR66V 
OUT_DIR=out
```

**Update#1**

Below are the compiler's commands that are used when compiling the Stack.cpp file which are shown using the build command `make -j4 libdvm showcommands`

It seems that the correct compiler is used as shown highlighted in bold below:

```
target thumb C++: libdvm <= dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper -I dalvik -I dalvik/vm -I external/zlib -I libcore/include -I dalvik/libattr -I external/stlport/stlport -I bionic/ -I bionic/libstdc++/include -I dalvik/vm -I out/target/product/manta/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper  -isystem system/core/include -isystem hardware/libhardware/include -isystem hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -isystem hardware/ril/include -isystem libnativehelper/include -isystem frameworks/native/include -isystem frameworks/native/opengl/include -isystem frameworks/av/include -isystem frameworks/base/include -isystem external/skia/include -isystem out/target/product/manta/obj/include -isystem bionic/libc/arch-arm/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/common -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/arch-arm -isystem bionic/libm/include -isystem bionic/libm/include/arm -isystem bionic/libthread_db/include -c  -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -msoft-float -fpic -fPIE -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -fno-short-enums -mcpu=cortex-a15 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -include build/core/combo/include/arch/linux-arm/AndroidConfig.h -I build/core/combo/include/arch/linux-arm/ -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-builtin-sin -fno-strict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-psabi -mthumb-interwork -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -DNDEBUG -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -fgcse-after-reload -frerun-cse-after-loop -frename-registers -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -fno-rtti  -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -fno-align-jumps -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -DARCH_VARIANT=\"armv7-a-neon\" -DDVM_SHOW_EXCEPTION=1 -DWITH_JIT -DANDROID_SMP=1   -MD -MF out/target/product/manta/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates/interp/Stack.d -o out/target/product/manta/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates/interp/Stack.o dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp
```

**Update#2:**

After changing the compile command-line to use -v to show the actual sub-tool commands that the g++ frontend invokes and adding the following compiler directives as suggested by @Peter Cordes

> `#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__i386__) #error "x86 What on earth" #endif`

Below is the output of the compiling after using the command `prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -v -o out/target/product/manta/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates/interp/Stack.o dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp`

Notice the error below (at the end of the compiling output) is because I removed all compiler parameters except -v and -o to shorten the output (it's about 2 pages), so I used only `prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/ar‌​m-linux-androideabi-‌​g++ -v -o`

When I do not remove all the original parameters (about 30), I do not get that error `fatal error: Dalvik.h: No such file or directory`

```
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -v -o out/target/product/manta/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates/interp/Stack.o dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-androideabi
Configured with: /tmp/AOSP-toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc-4.7/configure --prefix=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --with-mpc=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --with-cloog=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --with-ppl=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --disable-ppl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm --with-float=soft --with-fpu=vfp --with-arch=armv5te --enable-target-optspace --enable-initfini-array --disable-nls --prefix=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix --with-sysroot=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix/sysroot --with-binutils-version=2.22 --with-mpfr-version=3.1.1 --with-mpc-version=1.0.1 --with-gmp-version=5.0.5 --with-gcc-version=4.7 --with-gdb-version=7.3.x --with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix/include/c++/4.7 --with-bugurl=http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html --disable-bootstrap --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugins --enable-libgomp --enable-gold --enable-graphite=yes --with-cloog-version=0.17.0 --with-ppl-version=1.0 --with-arch=armv5te --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-linux-androideabi-&' --enable-gold=default
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'out/target/product/manta/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates/interp/Stack.o' '-march=armv5te' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/cc1plus -quiet -v -iprefix /home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/ -D_GNU_SOURCE dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp -mbionic -fpic -quiet -dumpbase Stack.cpp -march=armv5te -mfloat-abi=soft -mfpu=vfp -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase Stack -version -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -o /tmp/cctyR1ga.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7 (arm-linux-androideabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease), GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/../../include/c++/4.7"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/../../include/c++/4.7/arm-linux-androideabi"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/../../include/c++/4.7/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix/sysroot/usr/local/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix/sysroot/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/include
 /home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7 (arm-linux-androideabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease), GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c3359b46636f5ec5014b000ecf7eb5d5
dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp:23:20: fatal error: Dalvik.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

**Update#3:**

I wrote a simple C++ program called inlineAsm.cpp that uses an inline assembly code as suggested by @Peter Cordes which is shown below:

```
main()
{
int time, t0, t1, a;
{int pmccntr;asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr));t0=(pmccntr) * 64;}
a=1;
{int pmccntr;asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr));t1=(pmccntr) * 64;}
time = (t1-t0);
}
```

I compiled the above code using the following command:

```
 prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ inlineAsm.cpp
```

Below are the compiler error messages that I get:

```
/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lstdc++
/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lm
/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lc
/home/user/Android/nexus10/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is very strange because as I said before when I remove the inline assembly code that I added to the Android Stack.cpp source code, I can compile and build the ROM image for a Nexus10 which is ARM7a and the I can flash the image to the device and the image works fine with no problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the code is being built with the ARM cross-compiler, and not with a compiler targetting x86? You could find out by adding the `-v` flag to your `LOCAL_CFLAGS` for the module that the problematic code belongs to, and then checking the build logs

Comment: @Michael: I'm building the Android source code itself (not an app) after I add the inline assembly code to the [Stack.cpp](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp). How to find `LOCAL_CFLAGS` for that module and how to add `-v`? As I said before I followed the AOSP build guidelines and I did not change any steps.  I think I'm building for ARM and not x86 because when I remove the code that I added, the produced compiled ROM image works fine when I flash it to a Nexus 10 which is an ARM7a

Comment: Well, the problem is most definitely that, at some point, for some reason, that code is going through an x86 compiler - I don't know anything about the Android build process to be able to say _why_, though. That's not to say it doesn't get _also_ built for ARM along the way.

Comment: @Michael,@Notlikethat: as you can see from the update above, it seems that the correct compiler (for ARM) is being used to compile that file.

Comment: Try changing that compile command-line to use `-v` to show the actual sub-tool commands that the `g++` frontend invokes.  And maybe try adding `#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__i386__)` `#error "x86 WTF"` `#endif` to your source code to see if the preprocessor also "thinks" you're building for x86, because that's obviously what's happening.  Also maybe interesting to use an asm statement that declares a clobber on "`r1`" or something.  (Don't use `r8-r15`, x86-64 has registers with those names, too!).  That will break at compile time, rather than at assemble time.

Comment: `fatal error: Dalvik.h: No such file or directory`  Well that wasn't very interesting.  Did you even look at what you were posting?

Comment: Yes, that error is because I removed all compiler parameters except `-v` and `-o` to shorten the output (it's about 2 pages), so I used only `prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -v -o out/target/product/manta/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates/interp/Stack.o dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp`. When I do not remove all these parameters, I do not get that error `fatal error: Dalvik.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Maybe your cross-compile is broken.  Does it work correctly for building a simple program that uses inline-asm?  Is the compiler-generated asm actually ARM or x86, when you look at the `.s` file (`-S` output)?